# Qt building 64 bits

Tags: qt, build, 64-bit

I have downloaded the source package of Qt, and am trying to build a 64 bit version, on a 64 bit, Windows 7 machine.  I have read as much as I can on building Qt, but I must be missing something somewhere.

I open a 64 bit command shell, which some descriptions seem to think is the only thing necessary.

Next I call configure.  However, should I be specifying a platform option?  If so which one?  There doesn't seem to be a win64 option, or anything similar.

Then I call nmake, which builds a bunch of stuff, but it still builds in 32 bits.

What am I missing?  Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the configure command I run to build Qt 4.7.1 on 64-bit Windows. The compiled libraries are, indeed, 64-bit. This is run from the 64-bit command line. I'm using the Windows Platform SDK, not Visual Studio, but as long as you are running vcvars64.bat (or something like that), your environment should be set.

```
configure -plugin-sql-sqlite -no-qt3support -no-webkit -developer-build -opensource -platform win32-msvc2008
nmake
```

Comment: Actually, that is basically what we were doing wrong.  If you don't have the visual studio 64 bit command shell, that script is what you need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That seems the correct way to do it. Have you build a 32 bits Qt on the same source tree before? You might try to restart with a fresh Qt source directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance.  We finally figured out that we messed up the command shell.  You help was worth an up-vote :)